# Interactive buttons in video player

Tags: javascript, html, interactive

I am trying to make a simple index.php where I want to display a video but when the video reaches 20 seconds ask the user "Are you listening" or something like this.
After reading so many tutorials I achieved displaying the button on the 20th second but when I click on the button the video is not resuming for the next 20 seconds but for a few milliseconds.
The complete idea is to ask every 20 seconds "Are you listening"
Here is my code now:

```
<body>
  <div class="video-container">
    <video id="myVideo" controls>
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <button class="interactive-button" data-time="20">Are you listening carefully?</button>
    
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      const video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
      const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".interactive-button");

      buttons.forEach((button) => {
        const time = parseInt(button.dataset.time);
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
          if (video.currentTime >= time) {
            video.currentTime = time; 
            video.play(); 
          }
        });
      });

      video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
        const currentTime = video.currentTime;
        buttons.forEach((button) => {
          const time = parseInt(button.dataset.time);
          if (currentTime >= time) {
            button.style.display = "block";
            video.pause();
          } else {
            button.style.display = "none";
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is because you're checking for `time` always being `20`... if you want to check in another 20 then you need to increment the test value by 20 each iteration. If you only need one button you're making life difficult for yourself by having the `forEach`... instead give it an ID, and grab the single element. Then store the `time` as a separate variable and increase that value (rather than grabbing the dataset value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the timeupdate method, it is always checked whether the video time is greater than 20 seconds. Therefore, when it exceeds the 20-second mark, the video doesn't restart because it has already passed the 20-second mark.

You should update the button.dataset.time value each time.

```
buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const time = parseInt(button.dataset.time);
        if (video.currentTime >= time) {
            video.currentTime = time;
            button.dataset.time = time + 20;
            video.play();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working in this way :)